# Homogeneous equations for conic sections

Tags: linear-algebra, conic-sections, projective-geometry, homogeneous-equation

The equation of a "standard" circle is $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$.  That equation is not homogeneous and does not include the origin; we can homogenize it by adding a $z$ term of degree 2, getting $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$, a cone.

Given $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$, we can retrieve the circle of any $r$ by intersecting with $z = r$.

What if we want to do something similar for conics (not just circles)? Can we develop a homogeneous equation which allows us to take not only circles but any conics?

I imagine we would need to do something like $ex^2 + ey^2  = ez^3$, where $e$ is eccentricity.  However, I do not know how to complete this approach.

Another approach is to work with the original equation, but instead of solving for $z = r$, solve for $z = r + kx  + jy$, where $k$ and $j$ are arbitrary constants.  This seems more promising.  How would I express $k$ and $j$ in terms of eccentricity? And, since I don't care about rotation, can I just set $j = 0$, yielding $z = r + kx$? How does this relate to eccentricity?

Note: There are many references giving the general equations for conics.  However, these include translation, rotation, and sometimes skew.  I'm looking for a simple homogeneous equation which produces only "standard" conics, that is, intersecting a plane through a cone.  And, I'd like to be able to find the eccentricity, ideally having it appear in the equation.

---

## Update

If the question isn't clear, or needs more information, please comment with what's missing or how I can improve it.

If you have a partial answer or a start, please post it: it's still valuable.

If what I'm asking is fundamentally impossible or based on false assumptions, please post that at well.

Any response, positive or negative, complete or partial, is helpful.

Comment: The standard way is to set $z=1$ to get back, and parameters $(a,b,c,e,f_x,f_y)$ in the following don't count towards the homogeneity, so $(x-f_x z)^2+(y-f_y z)^2=e^2(a x+b y+ c z)^2/(a^2+b^2)$ would the homogeneous version of the focus/directrix form $(x-f_x)^2+(y-f_y)^2=e^2(a x+b y+ c)^2/(a^2+b^2)$ of the conic section for eccentricity $e,$ focus $F:(f_x,f_y)$ and corresponding directrix $d: ax +by +c=0.$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland I don't follow.  What is each of those parameters? What does "don't count towards the homogeneity" mean? And I'm asking for a restricted equation where the cone is fixed through the origin, thus the _only_ param should be eccentricity (and perhaps the z-plane distance from origin); the cone and plane don't admit translating focus and directrix.

Comment: Suppose we start with the all too familiar parabola $y=x^2$; imagine that this parabola resides in the horizontal plane $z=1$. Fix an arbitrary point on this parabola and draw a line passing through this point with the origin. If we do this for all points on $y=x^2,z=1$  we arrive at the surface obtained by replacing $x$ with $x/z$ and $y$ with $y/z$ which simplifies to $yz=x^2$. If we did this with the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1,z=1$ it's not hard to see that we get the surface of a cone which incidentally has formula $(x/z)^2+(y/z)^2=1$.

Comment: $ax^2+by^2=z^2$, with $a<b$, $a\ne0$, $b>0$, gives you, for $z=r$, a conic section with center at the origin, and eccentricity $\sqrt{1-(a/b)}$.

Comment: The parameters $a, b, c$ not all zero parametrize a general line to serve as the directrix for a focus, $e$ is your eccentricity, $f_x, f_y$ are the $x,y$-coordinates of the focus you're considering. For any given values of the parameters (the circle is a special case not considered) you get with the above a conic section. The standard homogenization is, as others have described, what I've given. I suppose you want something else, that's why I posted it as a comment. Maybe you want a parameter space for the conic sections depending on $e$?

Answer (score 1):

A homogeneous equation for one non-homogeneous parameter, the eccentricity $e,$ in two cases $e>0$ or $e=0:$ $$(F_z x-F_x z)^2+(F_z y-F_y z)^2=(A x+ B y+ C z)^2, e>0 $$ or $$(F_z x-F_x z)^2+(F_z y-F_y z)^2= (r z)^2, e=0, r>0.$$ To get back the metric properties, set $(F_x:F_y:F_z)=(f_x:f_y:1), z=1$ where $(f_x,f_y)$ is the the focus for the corresponding directrix $a x+b y+ c=0,$ with $a,b,c$ s.t $(A, B, C)=(ea, eb, ec), a^2+b^2=1.$ Note that we almost could unify the two cases with the circle being for $A=B=0,C=r,$ making $z=0$ (the line at infinity) the directrix.

As examples: a parabola $y-x^2=0:$ $x^2+(y-z/4)^2=(y+z/4)^2$

an ellipse $x^2+y^2/4-1=0:$ $x^2+(y+\sqrt3 z)^2=\frac34 (y+4z /\sqrt3)^2$ or $x^2+(y-\sqrt3 z)^2=\frac34 (y-4z /\sqrt3)^2$

a hyperbola $x^2-y^2/4-1=0:$ $(x+\sqrt5 z)^2+y^2=5 (x+z/\sqrt5)^2$ or $(x-\sqrt5 z)^2+y^2=5 (x-z/\sqrt5)^2$

Note that when you have two foci there is one representation of the equation for each focus.